# Unknown selector in CSS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I've come across a CSS selector that I've never seen before, and can't seem to find any reference to on google.

The selector is: `#{if(&, '&', '*')}.e-control-wrapper`

Am I right in thinking that it's basically saying that it doesn't care about what the ID is, just that it has one and that corresponding class?

Here's a broader example for reference.

```
.e-bigger .e-input-group-icon.e-date-icon,
#{if(&, '&', '*')}.e-control-wrapper.e-bigger .e-input-group-icon.e-date-icon,
#{if(&, '&', '*')}.e-bigger .e-control-wrapper .e-input-group-icon.e-date-icon {
    font-size: $datepicker-bigger-icon-font-size;
    margin: $datepicker-icon-bigger-margin;
    min-height: $datepicker-bigger-icon-container-min-height;
    min-width: $datepicker-bigger-icon-container-min-width;

    #{if(&, '&', '*')}::before {
        content: '\e901';
        font-family: 'e-icons';
    }

    #{if(&, '&', '*')}:focus {
        background: $hover-bg-color;
        border-radius: $datepicker-icon-border-radius;
    }
}
```

Updating to add further context based on what I've provided in the comments:

The SCSS block in question came from the SCSS file generated by this tool: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/themestudio/?theme=material

Since the generated SCSS is a bit clunky and repetitive, I've been going through breaking it down into manageable chunks and seeing whether I can cut some of the repetition down (for each Blazor element it seems to do a pass setting the structure, then override what it just set with thematic stuff - using a lot of the same selectors). As I hadn't seen anything of the sort before, I figured I'd see if anyone recognised that selector before tinkering too much and finding out the hard way.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be standard CSS...is this SCSS/SASS?

Comment: Yeah, plucked it out of the SCSS generated by this tool: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/themestudio/?theme=material - I noticed the SCSS was a clunky, sprawling mess that seemed to be doing a few things twice. It also uses the @at-root directive, which isn't recognised in the default Blazor SCSS compiler

Comment: As this appears to be SCSS it would be wise to tag the question accordingly. The answer you accepted assumes this is CSS, which it clearly isn't based on your source.

Comment: Apologies @BoltClock, I couldn't find SCSS - turns out it's flagged as SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that curly braces `{ }` represent a very specific syntax in CSS (ie. they contain *property-value* pairs), it's difficult to imagine how

```
#{if(&, '&', '*')}
```

might represent a valid CSS selector.

A simple experiment shows that this selector selects nothing:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

#{if(&, '&', '*')} {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="#{if(&, '&', '*')}"></div>
```

Comment: So, it's most likely that it's some arcane thing from whatever builder they used to generate it?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Exactly that.